# Birthday events area in Facebook Fan Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

As we all know, in a normal Facebook account you get a small Birthday events area in the upper-right corner of the screen. I was wondering is it possible to have the same feature for a fan page I created such that the birthdays of the people who liked the fan page will appear similar in my admin interface like a normal FB account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. DOB (when listed with a name) is part of the personal identifiable information and, thus, is protected by privacy agreements.